# Invalid Argument Running Google Go Binary in Linux

Tags: linux, go

I’ve written a very small application in Go, and configured an AWS Linux AMI to host. The application is a very simple web server. I’ve installed Go on the Linux VM by following the instructions in the official documentation to the letter. My application runs as expected when invoked with the “`go run main.go`” command.

However, I receive an “Invalid argument” error when I attempt to manually launch the binary file generated as a result of running “`go install`”. Instead, if I run “`go build`” (which I understand to be essentially the same thing, with a few exceptions) and then invoke the resulting binary, the application launches as expected.

I’m invoking the file from within the `$GOPATH/bin/` folder as follows:

```
./myapp
```

I’ve also added `$GOPATH/bin` to the `$PATH` variable.
I have also moved the binary from `$GOPATH/bin/` to the `src` folder, and successfully run it from there.

The Linux instance is a 64-bit instance, and I have installed the corresponding Go 64-bit installation.

Comment: probably unrelated (it must be some Go thing building a wrong format of executable): there's a fair amount of errors coming from linux and hard to recognize: for example, if executable format is ELF, but it doesn't specifies the ld.so (ld-linux.so) entrypoint properly, error would be "File not found". Anyway, run ldd on your binary to see if it's ok..

Comment: Output from ldd: linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd50dbb000)
        libpthread.so.0 => /lib64/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f6a5dc87000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x00007f6a5d8c6000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f6a5dea9000)

Comment: Try running strace on the bad executable. It will show all the system calls run by your program. All the libraries will read and shown in the system calls. Read the output to find out what failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`go build` builds *everything* (that is, all dependent packages), then produces the resulting executable files and then discards the intermediate results (see [this](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/06/04/what-does-go-build-build) for an alternative take; also consider carefully reading outputs of `go help build` and `go help install`).

`go install`, on the contrary, uses precompiled versions of the dependent packages, if it finds them; otherwise it builds them as well, and installs under `$PATH/pkg`. Hence I might suggest that `go install` sees some outdated packages which screw the resulting build.

Consider running `go install ./...` in your `$GOPATH/src`.
Or may be just selective `go install uri/of/the/package` for each dependent package, and then retry building the executable.

Comment: I've applied the steps that you outline, but the issue remains. Strangely, if I copy the binary generated from "go build" into the $GOPATH/bin folder, and attempt to execute it, I get the "Invalid argument" error. Yet it runs without issue when executed from the $GOPATH/src/myapp folder, after building.

Comment: You can just run `go install -a` (once) to force it to rebuild dependant packages if you suspect it's an out-of-date compiled package. Alternatively, you can delete everything in your `$GOPATH/pkg` directory and then `go install` will build fresh copies of each package the first time it's needed.

Comment: @PaulMooney, care to tun it under `strace` then (from the location where it fails)? Alternatively, try running it while having `LD_VERBOSE=1` in the environment to make the dynamic loader print what it does to bring up your program (see the `ld.so(8)` manual page).

Comment: Rebuilding the dependencies one-by-one revealed an error in one of the dependent packages. The dependent package also relied on a configuration file. Copying the file to $GOPATH/bin solved the "Invalid argument" problem.